# Accessing External Rest API from Sharepoint Modern site in Sharepoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

I want to access external API through sharepoint server 2019 modern teams/communication site hosted on-premises. Is there any out-of-the-box web part that enables the access to the external API?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Server 2019 on-premises does not have built-in web parts specifically designed for accessing external APIs. However, you can achieve this functionality by customizing SharePoint using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) or by developing custom solutions.